# Testing non-virtual methods using GMock

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, googletest, googlemock

how to use Google mocking in VC++ with Google testing for non-virtual methods with out modifying original code. 
For MFC VC++ (Dialog boxes). Where and How i can Implement GMock to my legacy code.
Can any one provide a Detailed explanation for these things.

Thank you.

Comment: why there is no reply?? need any details ???

Comment: [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Mike Kinghan. i followed all those rules. if u know any details then tell me. if it is confusing then ask.But try reply for my question.

Comment: You have asked *5* questions. 4 of them have something to do with gmock. 1 has nothing to do with gmock. Even if one person knew all the answers, why would they do all that work for you? - it would take days. I suggest that you delete everything except the first sentence and then show how you have tried to solve *that* problem yourself. Study [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [Google Test](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/) for testing these methods for correctness. Mocking out methods won't help you *test* them, it will help you test classes that *use* those methods, so it's probably not applicable in this case.

Also, per [Google Mock FAQ](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions):

> In order for a method to be mocked, it must be *virtual*, unless you use the [high-perf dependency injection technique](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#Mocking_Nonvirtual_Methods).